# How do I remove "my cart" from the left hand col in Magento?

Tags: magento, layout, cart

How do I remove the "my cart" section from the left hand column?

Answer (score -9, accepted):

You can set a CSS rule like this

```
.block-cart {
    display: none
}
```

Comment: Seriously ?????

Comment: Oh dear.  This is not going well.

Comment: It's the least invasive way of doing what I needed to do. Thanks Matteo :)

Comment: Yes, oh dear is correct. Fortunately I have run across stuff like this often enough that I now check for display:none when something isn't working the way it is supposed to. I've wasted too many hours in the past trying to solve problems introduced by display:none.

Comment: Well, this is the needed evil :) So the world is not perfect, but seems, that @Matteo suggested the best solution from "client's" perspective. The bad side of this is the unused markup and some extra loading time, but Cynthia is happy  with the result, then cheers!

Comment: @Matteo because it follows Magento theme development guidelines and seems, the community likes it. I my opinion it's better solution and people vote for it, because many people will hit this page from Google and other search engines and the community likes to point them to the better solution. As I understand the idea of Stack Overflow is not to give solutions of the problems, but also the educate ... your solution works for the Cynthia just the community doesn't like it. Nothing bad in that! Cheers!

Comment: This is a hack not a real solution.

Answer (score 17):

There are many ways to do that and it depends how your theme is built. If you have local.xml file in your theme, can you use this in your default handler:

```
<reference name="left">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>
</reference>
```

If you don't have local.xml file just create one in the layout folder of your theme and populate it with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="left">
            <action method="unsetChild"><name>cart_sidebar</name></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Clear the cache and you are ready to go.

Comment: I tried the local.xml option and my custom nav disappeared! Ack.

Comment: Are you sure, that this didn't happen, because you cleared the cache? Can you temporary remove / rename the local.xml file and to check what will happen?

Comment: clearing the cache shouldn't delete the menu I hardcoded in /templates/callouts/left_col.phtml.

Comment: What happened when you removed / renamed the local.xml file? Do you see again the custom navigation?

Comment: my code just reappeared all of a sudden. Magento is such a crazy beast. EVen after re-indexing and clearing cache, it was gone and then all of a sudden it was back.